# Query that accounts for changes in the hour of a timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

The problem is as follows. I have a table that contains the following columns:

| machine | timestamp | speed (meters/minute) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 22/9/2020, 16:45 | 15 |
| C1 | 22/9/2020, 16:55 | 5 |
| C1 | 22/9/2020, 17:20 | 19 |

What I want to know is the **distance** travelled in each hour for each machine, so I need to subtract the timestamp of the current row from the timestamp of the next row, and then multiply by the speed of the first row (e.g: 16:55 - 16:45 = 10 minutes -> 10 * 15 = 150 meters between 16:45 and 16:55).

I was able to do that by using a logic similar to the one below (it is not all the same query):

```
 ' 1st get the timestamp of the next row'
 lead(query."timestamp") OVER (PARTITION BY query.id ORDER BY query."timestamp") AS lead_timestamp
 ' 2nd get the duration'
 query."lead_timestamp" - query."timestamp" AS duration
 ' 3rd calculate the distance'
 query."duration" * query."speed" AS distance
 ' 4th group by hour'
 GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', CAST(query."timestamp" AS timestamp)
```

It works almost 100% fine. I get a table similar to the one below:

| machine | timestamp | duration (meters) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 22/9/2020, 16:00 | 275 |
| C1 | 22/9/2020, 17:00 | ... |

But as you can see, as I group data per hour, the total meters for the hour 16:00 are not correct because there wasn't a timestamp after the timestamp equal to "22/9/2020, 16:55" that forced the grouping to end at "22/9/2020, 16:59". So, in the end, I added to the hour 16:00 part of the duration for the hour 17:00 (those 20 minutes were added to hour 16:00).

I am not sure how to solve this problem but I have looked into UNION to add an 'artificial' row whenever there's a transition of hour between timestamps, before even starting subtracting values to calculate the duration. But it seems rather complicated since I would have to do it for each machine and I don't know how many rows it would be.

Can you help me? Thanks! If I was not clear pls ask for more info!

Comment: more info please. (because you are not clear)   Try to add "expected output". Also try to give **COMPLETE** SQL statements (the one you produced is missing the `SELECT`, and a final `)` )

Comment: Also, MySQL does not know the function `date_trunc()` ....

Answer (score 0):

This could be of help:

```
WITH cte as (
   select 'c1' as  machine, '2020-09-22 16:46' as timestamp, 15 as speed
   union all 
   select 'c1', '2020-09-22 16:56', 5
   union all 
   select 'c1', '2020-09-22 17:20', 19)
select 
   machine,
   timestamp,
   speed,
   lead(timestamp) over (partition by machine) nextTime,
   TIMEDIFF( lead(timestamp) over (partition by machine), timestamp) diffTime,
   minute(TIMEDIFF( lead(timestamp) over (partition by machine), timestamp))*speed meters
from cte;
```

output:

| machine | timestamp | speed | nextTime | diffTime | meters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | 2020-09-22 16:46 | 15 | 2020-09-22 16:56 | 00:10:00.000000 | 150 |
| c1 | 2020-09-22 16:56 | 5 | 2020-09-22 17:20 | 00:24:00.000000 | 120 |
| c1 | 2020-09-22 17:20 | 19 |  |  |  |